# Any way to access the filter funnel icon via keyboard in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

It's not in the official docs, but is there by any chance a non-documented/hacky keyboard shortcut for the little green filter funnel which has to be clicked to bring the "filter by" menu? Or else I am going to permanently damage my wrist soon by mouse-clicking that one icon hundreds of times (all the rest I do via keyboard!).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On window the shortcut

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>F</kbd>

toggles the filter of the selected cell on and off.

To open drop-down menu on filtered cell:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> then <kbd>R</kbd>

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+R does not work for me when the filter is currently applied on the column, ie, while the funnel is solid green. It only works when filter is not applied and the funnel is not solid green.

Comment: OK, I've got Ctrl+Alt+R working (sort of). The trick is to select the topmost cell (when solid green funnel), then unselect it by going down and then back on it again, then press CA+R. It just won't do it first time for some reason for me. I am now marking this as a solution. (Also, Ct+Alt+R is documented too.) Thanks!